# Is it possible to return "this" in generic interface with default implement using f-bounded quantification

Tags: java, generics, self, f-bounded-polymorphism

```
public interface IEq<T> {
  public abstract Boolean testEqual(final T y);

  public default Boolean testNotEqual(final T y) {
    return !this.testEqual(y);
  }
}

public interface IOrd<T> extends IEq<T> {
  public abstract Boolean lessEqualThan(final T y);

  public default T min(final T y) {
    if(lessEqualThan(y)) return this; // <--- ERROR: cannot convert from IOrd<T> to T
    else return y;
  }
}
```

This OOP style code is very simlilar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification.

The difference is I move the external function (Fmin) to Object method (min)

My question is: Is it possible to return "this" in the generic interface (IOrd) with default implement (min: T -> T) using f-bounded quantification?

Comment: Why do you return `Iord<T>` in a method which return `T` ???

Comment: I think the problem that the OP is having is that he can't constrain `T` to the "current type". @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: Usually, you use `public interface IEq<T extends IEq<T>>` and `public interface IOrd<T extends IOrd<T>> extends IEq<T>`. This should avoid the problems.

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn Because if I return IOrd<T>, then the min method will lose the return value polymorphism which f-bounded gave me. eg: `NaturalNumber nat = ...; nat.min(x) will return IOrd<NaturalNumber> instead of NaturalNumber` that is not what I want

Comment: @JohannesKuhn No, it doesn't work (cannot convert from IOrd<T> to T), except mandatory cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `IOrd<T>` in a method which return `T`. You have to change your signature:

```
public abstract Boolean lessEqualThan(final IOrd<T> y);


public default IOrd<T> min(final IOrd<T> y) {
    if(lessEqualThan(y)) return this;
    else return y;
}
```

If you want to return `T` you must provide a way to get the `T` value from your implementation class:

```
public abstract Boolean lessEqualThan(final T y);

T getTValue(); // Your implementation must provide a way to get the T value

public default T min(final T y) {
    if(lessEqualThan(y)) return getTValue();
    else return y;
}
```